# How to join date and time column of type object to datetime column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have date and time column as follows

[image]

I need to combine the 2 columns to make it look like 01-10-2022 00:00:00 , when I do df.info(), I get the dtype as object. Can anyone please tell me how to convert and combine the 2 columns as datetime.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['CAPTURE_DATE'] + ' ' + df['CAPTURE_TIME'])`

Comment: Before writing a question, try to search SO first. It’s most likely someone else already had similar issue.